# how to change currency format in magento2?

Tags: magento2

how to change currency format in magento2?
for example:
I want to transfer the currency symbol to the left of the price in the following format
[image]

Comment: can you try this extension :
https://github.com/mage2pro/currency-format

Comment: You have to override getPriceFormat() of Magento\Framework\Locale\Format class and add your own logic and if you are able to override your locale XML file from here  vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/ then there is a node for the currency format... From admin you can only change the currency symbol not the format.